# Not able to integrate AWS lex with web

Tags: amazon-lex

Here is my index.html file. I have required loading lex-web-ui.js and config.js files in script but still getting the error.
The error I am getting is ChatBotUiLoader is not defined

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Parent Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my parent page</h1>
    <!-- loader script -->
    <script src="./dist/lex-web-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      /*
        The loader library creates a global object named ChatBotUiLoader
        It includes the IframeLoader constructor
        An instance of IframeLoader has the load function which kicks off
        the load process
      */

      // options for the loader constructor
      var loaderOptions = {
        // you can put the chatbot UI config in a JSON file
        configUrl: './config.json',

        // the full page chatbot UI that will be iframed
        iframeSrcPath: './chatbot-index.html#/?lexWebUiEmbed=true'
      };

      // The following statement instantiates the IframeLoader
      var iframeLoader = new ChatBotUiLoader.IframeLoader(loaderOptions);

      // chatbot UI config
      // The loader can also obtain these values from other sources such
      // as a JSON file or events. The configUrl variable in the
      // loaderOptions above can be used to put these config values in a file
      // instead of explicitly passing it as an argument.
      var chatbotUiConfig = {
        ui: {
          // origin of the parent site where you are including the chatbot UI
          // set to window.location.origin since hosting on same site
          parentOrigin: window.location.origin,
        },
        iframe: {
          // origin hosting the HTML file that will be embedded in the iframe
          // set to window.location.origin since hosting on same site
          iframeOrigin: window.location.origin,
        },
        cognito: {
          // Your Cognito Pool Id - this is required to provide AWS credentials
          poolId: 'xxx'
        },
        lex: {
          // Lex Bot Name in your account
          botName: 'xxx'
        }
      };

      // Call the load function which returns a promise that is resolved
      // once the component is loaded or is rejected if there is an error
      iframeLoader.load(chatbotUiConfig)
        .then(function () {
          console.log('iframe loaded');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to integrate AWS lex on my website. I am using this repo https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/tree/master/dist
But getting an error: ChatBotUiLoader is not defined. Can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0KLQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the error is that an instance of `ChatBotUiLoader` cannot be created as the library/script containing that object was not found within the scope of the page.

It could be that the demo application is broken but the fix is fairly simple.

You need to include the [`lex-web-ui-loader.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/master/dist/lex-web-ui-loader.js) script file (and its dependencies) in your web page to resolve the issue.